# disable next/prev at the start/end of the list

Tags: jquery, traversal

I want to be able to hide/disable the prev link when I am at the first box and disable the next link at the last box because at the moment you can keep clicking on next at the last box and when you do this it breaks as clicking previous no longer works. [see demo in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/FmQNZ/)

```
<span id="wrapper">
<span id="prev"><a href="#">Go to Prev</a></span>
<span id="content">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div id="start" class="box">6</div>
    <div class="box">7</div>
</span>
<span id="next"><a href="#">Go to Next</a></span>
```

```
    var $curr = $("#start");
$curr.css("display", "inline");
$("#prev a").click(function () {
  $curr = $curr.prev();
  $(".box").css("display", "");
  $curr.css("display", "inline");
});

$("#next a").click(function () {
  $curr = $curr.next();
  $(".box").css("display", "");
  $curr.css("display", "inline");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way:

http://jsfiddle.net/mBXYL/

```
var $curr = $("#start");
$curr.css("display", "inline");
$("#prev a").click(function() {
    $curr = $curr.prev();
    $(".box").css("display", "");
    $curr.css("display", "inline");
    $("#next").show();
    if (!$curr.prev().length) {
        $("#prev").hide();
    }
});

$("#next a").click(function() {
    $curr = $curr.next();
    $(".box").css("display", "");
    $curr.css("display", "inline");
    $("#prev").show();
    if (!$curr.next().length) {
        $("#next").hide();
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** to respect your project needs:

### *[jsFiddle demo (hides buttons)](http://jsfiddle.net/LBzK7/3/)*

```
var currN = 5;
var boxN = $('#content .box').length;
$('#content .box').eq(currN).show();

function displayBox(){
    pr= currN === 0      ? $('#prev').hide() : $('#prev').show() ;
    nx= currN === boxN-1 ? $('#next').hide() : $('#next').show() ;
    $('.box').eq(currN).show().siblings().hide();
}

$("#prev, #next").click(function () {
    var whichBtn = this.id==='next' ? currN++ : currN--;
    displayBox();
});
```

---

You dont need to disable your buttons, make a **loop!**

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LBzK7/)*

```
var $curr = $("#start");
var currN = $curr.index();
var boxN = $('#content .box').length;

$curr.css("display", "inline");

function displayBox(){
    if(currN === -1){
        currN = boxN-1;
    }else{
       currN = currN % boxN;
    }
    $('.box').eq(currN).show().siblings().hide();
}


$("#prev a").click(function () {
    currN--;
    displayBox();
});

$("#next a").click(function () {
    currN++;
    displayBox();
});
```

---

I created here a simplified version (you don't need the `#start`) :

### *[jsFiddle demo 2 (simplified)](http://jsfiddle.net/LBzK7/1/)*

THis is all you need:

```
var currN = 5;   // set here start slide! (zero index based)
var boxN = $('#content .box').length;
$('#content .box').eq(currN).show();

function displayBox(){
    var curBox = currN === -1 ? currN=boxN-1 : currN=currN%boxN;
    $('.box').eq(currN).show().siblings().hide();
}

$("#prev, #next").click(function () {
    var whichBtn = this.id==='next' ? currN++ : currN--
    displayBox();
});
```

Comment: thanks this will come in handy at some stage but the requirements for my project here are to disable it.

Comment: @ak85 Thanks for your reply (took some time :) ) I reedited my answer to add a bit cleaner code for your needs.