# If last child, do this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm  creating a simple slideshow.

http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/Br5HJ/

It works great, until the user clicks `.right` on the last child. I need the process to start again:

```
$('.slide-list .img:first-child').addClass('active').clone()
    .appendTo('.main-slide');

$('.slide-list .img').click(function () {
    $('.slide-list .img').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.main-slide').empty();
    $(this).clone().appendTo('.main-slide');
});

$('.right').click(function () {
        $('.main-slide').empty();
        $('.active.img').removeClass('active')
            .next()
            .addClass('active').clone().appendTo('.main-slide');
});
```

However, I'm unsure how to implement such a statement.

Comment: check this one out, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569846/disable-next-prev-at-the-start-end-of-the-list there is an answer which disables arrow on last and one that loops through!

Comment: you could probably check if its the last node and then can use the `addClass` to the first node and remove the class from the last object, have you tried this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have just corrected your code:** you need to use jQuery's `is(':last-child')` condition and selector + jQuery's `.first()` selector method references:

http://api.jquery.com/is/

http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/first/

```
    $('.slide-list .img:first-child').addClass('active').clone()
        .appendTo('.main-slide');

    $('.slide-list .img').click(function () {
        $('.slide-list .img').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.main-slide').empty();
        $(this).clone().appendTo('.main-slide');
    });

    function cycler(d) {
        d = (d=="right"); //right=true, left=false
        $('.main-slide').empty();
        if( $('.active.img').is( (d?':last-child':':first-child') ) ){
            $('.active.img').removeClass('active');
            $('.slide-list .img')[d?'first':'last']()
            .addClass('active')
            .clone()
            .appendTo('.main-slide');
        } else{
            $('.active.img').removeClass('active')[d?'next':'prev']()
            .addClass('active').clone().appendTo('.main-slide');
        }

    };
    $('.right').click( function(){ cycler('right'); } );
    $('.left').click( function(){ cycler('left'); } );
```

See the http://jsfiddle.net/2FVQm/ - the right arrow is now cycling right (original answer fiddle) ;)

**Updated answer fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/F8a7v/ (general cycling left||right by given direction "`d`")

Comment: That's brilliant. I've done the same with `.left`, too: http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/2FVQm/3/ Although I'm repeating a lot of code. Is there a way you recommend I mean this better? (Pretty much the same code, just words like 'prev, next, last:child, first:child, last, first, left, right seem to differ.

Comment: sure, w8 a minute please

Comment: @tmyie we will help us with the special `object['parametr']()` call (same as `obejct.parameter()`) So we could finely use the ternary operator in our stored function :) So here it comes: http://jsfiddle.net/F8a7v/

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
$('.right').click(function () {
    $('.main-slide').empty();
    if($('.active.img').is(':last-child')) {
        $('.active.img').removeClass('active');
        $('.img:first').addClass('active').clone().appendTo('.main-slide');
    } else {
        $('.active.img').removeClass('active')
        .next()
        .addClass('active').clone().appendTo('.main-slide');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **.index()** http://api.jquery.com/index/ to get the index of the current slide, if index is equal to the number of the slider minus one, then you are at the end.

I developed a very minimal slider time ago http://romanovian.com/blog/laboratorio/jquery-minislider/, maybe give it a look.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest change you can do is to check whether `next` element is present, and manipuplate DOM accordingly:

```
$('.right').click(function () {
        $('.main-slide').empty();
    if($('.active.img').next().length > 0){ /* CHECK IF LAST ELEMENT */
        $('.active.img').removeClass('active')
            .next()
            .addClass('active').clone().appendTo('.main-slide');
    }
    else
    {
        /* START OVER FROM FIRST ELEMENT */ 
        $('.active.img').removeClass('active');
       $('.img').first().addClass('active').clone().appendTo('.main-slide');
    }
});
```

**demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/Br5HJ/16/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.right').click(function () {
        $('.main-slide').empty();
    if(!$('.active.img:last-child').hasClass("active"))
    {
        $('.active.img').removeClass('active')
            .next()
            .addClass('active').clone().appendTo('.main-slide');
    }
    else{
        $(".slide-list .img:last-child").removeClass("active");
        $('.slide-list .img:first-child').addClass('active').clone()
    .appendTo('.main-slide');
    }

});
```